# React Apollo queries that rely on other queries

Tags: reactjs

I have some queries in a react page that rely on other queries before it on the same page. What is the best way of handling this?

```
const { data, loading, error, fetchMore } = useQuery(GET_ALL_NOTIFS, {
    variables: { id, limit: 5 },
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  });

  const { data: notifTypes } = useQuery(GET_NOTIF_TYPES, {
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  });
   
  // The data in this one relys on the 
  const { data: selectedEquipment } = useQuery(GET_EQUIPMENT_BY_IDS, {
    variables: { } // The variable here relies on the data from the first query its supposed to be an arrayof ids looking like this {ids: data.ids}
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  });
```

Ive tried using useLazyQuery with a useEffect and data as a dependency but is there another way of doing this?

Comment: I didn't understand well, give me more examples

Comment: do you have access to the api? this seems like something that could fixed by writing it in a single query another simple way of handling this is split the queries up into its own components

Comment: The data in the first query from the api is a list of objects and each item has a field Id which I need to collect them all into a list of ids to send them to the third query as a variable parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ApolloConsumer to get the client and use it as

```
const { data, loading, error } = await client.query (....);
...
```